# Apply conditions using closure on Laravel Model collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, method-chaining, laravel-collection

I am using Laravel Model collection and want to filter the records
in the first statement, I am checking that I only check the ends when it's has some date otherwise doesn't compare the value.
How to check the null value in this collection?

2nd if is working properly. I also used the filter method but it's not working for me. Can anyone suggest to me how to do this in a proper laravel way? I know I can do this using for each loop but I want to make the query faster. Please suggest your answers. Thank you

```
$subscriptionsCount = Subscription::where( function($query) {
if($query->where('ends_at', '!=' , null)){
  $query->where('ends_at', '>=', now());
}
else if($query->where('subscription_ends_at', '>=', now())){
  $query->where('subscription_ends_at', '>=', now());
}
})->where('name', $betTypeName)->count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code as I understood from your question you need `whereNotNull`

```
     $subscriptionsCount = Subscription::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('ends_at')->where('ends_at', '>=', now());
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('subscription_ends_at')
                  ->where('subscription_ends_at', '>=', now());
        });
    })->where('name', $betTypeName)->count();
```

Comment: you are very close to solving my answer, can you please tell me how can I check that if the first query is not running, then I am going to execute the subscription_ends_at query. Basically, I am first matching records with ends_at and if this will not set I want to get the results from subscription_end_at.

Comment: it's still not, actually I need that if the first query is running then I don't want to execute the 2nd query. or condition will exe the second query. I need when condition but I don't know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below whereRaw condition :

```
$subscriptionsCount = Subscription::where( function($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("(CASE  WHEN ends_at is not null THEN ends_at = now() WHEN subscription_ends_at >= now() THEN subscription_ends_at >= now() END)" );
})->where('name', $betTypeName)->count();
```

Hope Above code will be help you. Code is not tested but logic will help you. :)

Comment: yes it's working as I expected, but want to do this stuff with laravel don't want to use the raw queries, can you please do it for me, thank you so much for your contribution

Comment: For this kind of logical where condition whereRaw is preferred.   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw